# How can i get value from JSON response in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello i have response from JSON in which i have got array with the following values now my question is how can i get this value from this and store is in individual NSString.

```
{"Id”:”10”,”Profile”:”2”,”Name”:”admin”,”LastName”:”admin”,”pic”:”default.png","Email”:”admin@gmail.com","Configuration”:”{\”Id\”:\”1\”,\”Notification\”:\”1\”}”
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting response is not in array format.It is in dictionary format because

```
[ ] is array 
{ } is dictionary
```

According to your posted question you get the response in dictionary format as it starts with { }. 
So you have to get the response in dictionary first.After that follow my below answer.

```
NSString *stringId = dictJson[@"Id"];
NSString *stringProfile = dictJson[@"Profile"];
NSString *stringName = dictJson[@"Name"];
NSString *stringLastName = dictJson[@"LastName"];
NSString *stringEmail = dictJson[@"Email"];
```

Comment: Don't use `valueForKey:` to get data from a dictionary. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a specific use for KVC. And don't needlessly use `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: The first one is already a string too so no need for `stringWithFormat`. Even easier than `objectForKey:` is modern syntax. `NSString *name = dictJson[@"Name"];`. And you should add an explanation to your answer. Basically put your question comment into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First Convert your JSON response into NSArray .

```
   NSArray *arrJsonResponse = i  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

Now you can get Dictionary by using

```
  [array objectAtIndex:myIndex] method of the NSArray
```

Then after you can refer the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *stringId = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Id"]
NSString *stringProfile = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Profile"];
NSString *stringName = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
NSString *stringLastName = [dictionary valueForKey:@"LastName"];
NSString *stringEmail = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Email"];
```